# how to get generated *.m/*.h files to be recognized in XCode4 for compilation etc?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I've got some autogenerated *.m and *.h files (from mogenerator) that I have put into a directory "mogen" in my project.  What I did was add this directory into my project using "Add Files..." and the referencing approach.

They now appear in the project, however classes trying to IMPORT the header files are getting "no such file or directory"

How do I get, in XCode 4, the classes/header files to be compiled such that they're available to the rest of the project.  For example:

- do I need to manually add them to TARGET/BuildPhases/CompiledSources
- other approach?
- ideally the approach would automatically work when more auto-generated classes & header files appear

Comment: When you say "import", what do you mean? Xcode doesn't use that particular terminology. Also, are the file names generated by mogenerator different every time they are generated? Or are they static?

Comment: oh yes - it's "Add Files..." I should have said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all that was required was to manually add each of the new *.m files (not *.h files) to the TARGET/BuildPhases/CompiledSources area.

(i.e. not the directory - pity it wasn't possible to just add the directory and have XCode4 pickup automatically any new changes/additions of classes to the directory)